# Too many header lines error in perl

Tags: perl, cookies

I wrote a simple perl code:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use strict;                                                               
use warnings;                                                               
use LWP;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5) Gecko/20060719 Firefox/1.5.0.5');
my $res = $ua->get('http://60606.com/members/search',Cookie => 'incomerr_refid=0; ff_language_id=3; _t_=1; fcode2=4139; ss_time=1527663671; PHPSESSID=otfmog35f0iva0uld1rgld2kj7; _webpush_key_=none; dinged_id=1412807; _language_id=3; _gnum_=950212; refid=1; first_key=TOCz19ls8HfkFW6LoBrIj35p4xSyYPVE; last_valid_url=https%3A//60606.com/login; ping_last=1527663675.939');
print $res->content;
```

but when I run it I get this error:

```
Too many header lines (limit is 128) at C:/Perl64/lib/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 377
```

Please tell me why I get this error, I think it's for cookie format

Comment: Works for me...returns a web page..but I'm on Ubuntu with perl 5.24.1

Comment: You can use [LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere) to get the communication that happens in the background. Take a look at the headers of the response. They should come out before they are parsed and it breaks. Also please [edit] and tell us what version of Perl and Net::HTTP and LWP::UserAgent you have. You can do `perl -MLWP::UserAgent\ 99` with a space after the backslash ``\`` for both modules. The [N::HTTP changelog](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Net-HTTP) doesn't speak of this though.

Comment: When the cookie is incorrect it works, I tested with set_cookie but it get the same error

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell me why I get this error, I think it's for cookie format

The error speaks about the number of lines in the header. That's not related to the cookie header, as that is only a single line.

The place where [Net::HTTP::Methods](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::HTTP) complains is [when it reads the incoming response header lines](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/Net-HTTP-6.18/lib/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm#L374). Those [are set to 128 by default](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/Net-HTTP-6.18/lib/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm#L80), but this can be changed with an argument.

However, I haven't figured out a way yet to inject a different value. I've reproduced the problem stand-alone though.

```
$ perl -Mojo -E \
 'a(sub ($c) { $c->res->headers->header("X-$_" => $_) for 1..128; $c->render(text => "Hello") })->start' \
  daemon
```

This will give you a server on localhost:3000 that responds with loads of header lines. If you then make a response, the same problem occurs.

```
my $res = $ua->get('http://localhost:3000/');
```

Unfortunately that does not help us very much.

Comment: I think this is one for #lwp on IRC. I can't find anything.

Comment: `use LWP::Protocol::http; push @LWP::Protocol::http::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS, MaxHeaderLines => 256;` should extend the limit.